# Creating a layout with mutiple Imageviews behind one another

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to create a layout where images can be loaded behind another. 
Heres an example:
[image]

How would I create a layout like so? Or maybe theres a library that I'm unaware of?

So far I only figured out in creating the background of single circle image views:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/dividerColor"/>
    <padding
        android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp"/>

</shape>
```

And setting the background to this `drawable` and loading it with glide. How would I create a layout where they are behind each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create this kind of layout using `LinearLayout` (horizontal orientation) and `ImageView`, just add `android:layout_marginStart="-20dp"` with each of ImageView Horizontally.

You can also add the ImageView dynamically using `view.addView(imageView)`.

Or You can use this library for the same implementation [StackImageView](https://github.com/KartikPrajapati/StackImageView)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle_background_on"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle_background_on"
        android:tint="@color/red"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle_background_on"
        android:tint="@color/green"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

I personally use `FrameLayout`for such kind of UI requirements.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/shape_1"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/shape_2"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/shape_3"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp" />


</FrameLayout>
```

[image]